Spring Boot JPA Entity Insert on conflict do nothing
I have the following JPA entity with an association
@Getter
@Entity
@Builder
class Entity {

   @Transient
   private boolean isNew = true;

   @Id
   private UUID id;
   
   @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) 
   private ParentEntity parent;

   private long version; 

    ....
   
   @PrePersist
   @PostLoad
   void markNotNew() {
      this.isNew = false;
   }
}

@Getter
@Entity
@Builder
class ParentEntity {

   @Transient
   private boolean isNew = true;

   @Id
   private UUID id; // id will be generated in advance not by hibernate
   
    ...

   private long version; 

    @PrePersist
    @PostLoad
    void markNotNew() {
        this.isNew = false;
    }
   
}

Imagine application is deployed in multiple machines and at the same time from different application users may create an Entity record for the same parent.

// process 1 on machine1
Entity e1 = ..;
entityRepository.save(e1);

// process 2 on machine 2
Entity e1 = ..;
entityRepository.save(e1);

Currently I am getting duplicate key value violates unique constraint error, it complains that parent entity already exists.
My requirement is it should insert the new child Entity in database and do nothing with parent if already exists (just on conflict do nothing).
